# TFS 2017: Change default column width of ID

Tags: tfs

We have upgradet to TFS 2017, which has been very nice. Until then, the column of the ID column on "All links" tab in an task is too narrow (see red rectangle):

[image]

The column can be widened with the mouse, but this must be done every time entering a task. I checked it with IE, Firefox and Edge. Everywhere the same problem. Does anybody know how to fix the column with at a larger width.

Comment: [Design the work item form](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/design-work-item-form) is probably the right place to *start* with understanding the customization process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot, you are using the old form of workitem in webside.

Unfortunately,  there is no way to do that on old form for now. And there has been a related uservoice:

> **Increase default width for "ID" column or make it automatically adjustable in LINK controls**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/6439132-increase-default-width-for-id-column-or-make-it

However as a workaround, you could **use the new form** instead of old form on TFS2017. Just turn on it as follow screenshot (click *`Try the new form`*):

[image]

Then you should get a new layout of the work item, under the links, the work items IDs should be shown without truncating.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Currently I don't have the link "Try the new form". Do you know how to enable it?

Comment: @scher Screenshot with [TFS2017update1](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2017-update1), since you are working on TFS2017, guess it's a new feature released on update1.